# picture viewer in c# .net

Tags: c#, image-processing

Regarding .Net technology,What will be the basic element of a picture viewer(like Windows Picture and Fax Viewer)? Is it a user control inside a form, or is it something other components. Could you please give me an idea in the context of C#.Net

Comment: you can use `Picture` control simply to display images.

Comment: @Ummar: I would like to do 1. Zooming 2. Magnifier etc . Does Picture control support all these functionalities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really get one that's bundled into .NET Framework (and that's probably a good thing, it's fairly large already).

If using WinForms, the nearest thing you do get is the `PictureBox` component, and the `BackgroundImage` property of some other components like `Form` and `Panel`. But you have to implement the rest of the functionality of an image viewer yourself.

WPF certainly has its own equivalents but I can't name them off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

for making picture viewer is better to have PictureBox to show Pictures, ImageList   to hold list of images due to have more that one picture and also two buttons for next   pictur and previews picture.

a simple code which I suggest is as follow:

```
private void btnLoadImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        imageList1.Images.Clear();
        if (openFDialogImage.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < openFDialogImage.FileNames.Length; i++)
            {

imageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(openFDialogImage.FileNames[i]));
            }
            pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.Images[currentIndex];
        }
    }

    private void BtnForward_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(currentIndex!=imageList1.Images.Count-1 && imageList1.Images.Count > 0)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.Images[currentIndex++];
        }


    }

    private void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (currentIndex!=0)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.Images[--currentIndex];
        }
    }
```

Thats all, :)